# Use of Parentheses in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I came across the following JavaScript in Kyle Simpson's @kyle-simpson book [Functional-Light JavaScript](https://github.com/getify/Functional-Light-JS) and am curious about part of its syntax:

```
    const double = v => v * 2;

    const reducer = (list, v) => (list.push(double(v)), list);

    var doubled = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reduce(reducer, []);

    console.log(doubled);
    //[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

    var reduced = reducer([3], 2);

    console.log(reduced);
    //[3, 6]
```

Specifically I am not certain about the meaning and usage of the outer parentheses surrounding the reducer function's return value:

```
(list.push(double(v)), list)
```

Wrapping a object literal in parentheses is a way to implicitly return it from an  arrow function but this appears to be something different.

Also:

```
var val = (3, 2);

console.log(val);
//2
```

This seems to suggest the parentheses will return the last value in its list, which would match the signature of the reducer function, but I do not know what this construct is called.

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: This is known as comma operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Comment: *Hints*: `(3, 4)` evaluates to 4. So does `(console.log('side-effect'), 4)`.

Comment: I love to use comma in `reduce` for side-effects on stackoverflow comments, because it makes very short code. However, i don't know if it's a good idea in production code, possibly less readable than writing out a code block.